# How to get the values from post method to the codehind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, post, hidden-field

I have created a Webpage which will post as "post" method..not as "get" method.

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<FORM action="RetrieveData_Post.asp" id=form1 method=post name=form1>
 First Name:
 <br>
 <INPUT id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" >
 <br>
 Last Name:
 <br>
 <INPUT id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" >
 <br>
 <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to retieve the values in the textboxes in the code behind of another form. Please help me.

Comment: you write: action="RetrieveData_Post.asp" and then you tag it as ASP.NET ? Is this ASP or ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the form fields of a request in the `HttpContext`:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form
```

or, to cover cookies, form, query string and server variables use either the `Item` or `Params` collection of the `HttpRequest` instance.

(In code behind, the `Page` base type has a `Request` property to avoid going via `HttpContext`.)

Comment: He writes the form action should be Classic ASP (RetrieveData_Post.asp) ... why change the action if we can do everything and even redirect/transfer in the Page_Load event from what the form contains?

Answer (score 1):

Change action="RetrieveData_Post.asp" to action="RetrieveData_Post.aspx" create the aspx page and use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form
```

for retrive values.